# Term Document matrix manual implementation. Can we make it more efficient?

Tags: python-3.x

The code below just produce the term-document matrix. Can we make it more efficient?

```
PREPROCESSED = ['He is a good boy','he loves studying']
DICTIONARY = ['He', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'boy', 'loves', 'studying']
MATRIX = []
for sent in PREPROCESSED:
    temp = []
    for i in DICTIONARY:
        count = 0
        for words in sent.split():
            if i == words:
                count = count + 1
        temp.append(count)
    test = 0
    for i in temp:
        if i != 0:
            test = 1
    if test == 1:
        MATRIX.append(temp)
    del temp
```

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, [codereview.se] might be a better fit.

Comment: yes. This is working code. I think some tricks could help me to reduce the loops and save memory.

Comment: It would also be helpful to provide a bit of context, e.g. example inputs and outputs so people don't have to puzzle through what it does by inspection.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to rework the algorithm, but you can't really do better than  [image: O(n * m)]

The code with some minor(but good if the lists grow a lot) changes:

```
PREPROCESSED = ['He is a good boy','he loves studying']
DICTIONARY = ['He', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'boy', 'loves', 'studying']
MATRIX = []
for sent in PREPROCESSED:
    temp = []
    tmpSent = sent.split() #runs once instead of len(DICTIONARY) times
    for i in DICTIONARY:
        count = 0
        for word in tmpSent:
            if i == word:
                count += 1
        temp.append(count)
    for i in temp:
        if i != 0:
          # removes an extra test
          MATRIX.append(temp)
          break
    del temp

print(MATRIX)
```